# Loop on variadic templates types at runtime

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I migrate a code from C++11 to C++17. In that code I do something like this (non-valid) code:

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::vector<std::size_t> store_types()
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> t;
    for(typename T : Ts)
        t.push_back(typeid(T).hash_code());
    return t;
}
```

For the moment, my implementation is the following:

```
template <typename Unused>
void add_types_in(std::vector<std::size_t>&)
{}

template <typename Unused, typename First, typename... Others>
void add_types_in(std::vector<std::size_t>& t)
{
    t.push_back(typeid(First).hash_code());
    add_types_in<Unused, Others...>(t);
}

template <typename... Ts>
std::vector<std::size_t> store_types()
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> t;
    add_types_in<void*, Ts...>(t);
    return t;
}
```

I see a lot a variadic functionalities in C++17, but there is a lot of things I don't understand yet. **Is there something more elegant** (aka more "one-line") **in C++17 than my implementation ?** Maybe something similar to fold expressions ?

Comment: Seeing `typeid` hashes is a bit unusual. Perhaps `std::type_index` could be used here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no no it's okay. I need a basic type that I can save and load in any format (binary, text, ...) in order to identify types. `std::type_info::hash_code` is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Caduchon `hash_code` is not guaranteed unique nor is it guaranteed stable over different executions of your program (or changes in your compiler).  It is **not suitable for serialization** into a non-transient binary format.  (In practice, it will be stable over different executions, I'm just saying I don't believe there is a guarantee: but probably not to be relied on over over compiler changes)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont "std::type_info::hash_code returns an unspecified value (here denoted by hash code) such that for all std::type_info objects referring to the same type, their hash code is the same." It's exactly what I need. I don't have to justify that here, it's not my question.

Comment: `hash_code` cannot identify types (there *can* be collisions). If you want something with similar properties but with no collisions, use `inline std::size_t counter() { static std::atomic<std::size_t> count{0}; if (std::size_t x = ++count; x == 0) throw "Too many types"; else return x; } template<typename T> inline const std::size_t type_hash_code = counter();` (where `type_hash_code<T>` will probably run faster than `typeid(T).hash_code()`)

Comment: @Caduchon I'm just giving a caution!  You stated you wanted to use it to identify types and save/load it, and it does none of those things safely; it can only be (safely) used to *distinguish* types from each other, and only over one execution of the program.  `.hash_code() != .hash_code()` means they are different, but `.hash_code()==.hash_code()` does not mean they are the same!  Hashes are not identities (except in cases like merkle trees which uses them as an identity, but that is a special case with a hash with special properties)

Comment: I know the collide risk. It's already managed. I don't need to keep the same value from an execution to another. I just have to compare hash codes of types already known to have no possible collision. The recognition of type is guaranteed by the order of the types in the c++ code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector` can be initialized with a list of values so you can just expand the pack directly in a *braced-init-list* like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::vector<std::size_t> store_types()
{
    return { typeid(Ts).hash_code()... };
}
```

If you want to avoid dynamic allocation, you can switch to use a `std::array` like:

```
// C++11 or 14
template <typename... Ts>
auto store_types() -> std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>
{
    return { typeid(Ts).hash_code()... };
}

// or
// C++17
template <typename... Ts>
auto store_types()
{
    return std::array{ typeid(Ts).hash_code()... };
}
```

Comment: I would use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: So beautiful ! :-o

Comment: @MarekR Good idea, I've add a couple of ways to do that.

Comment: @MarekR not in my case. The goal is to dump/load data.

Comment: @Caduchon Do note that this is just plain old pack expansion, not a fold expression, so this technique is valid starting in C++11.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/e18rEEddx

Comment: @MarekR The lowest (least?) C++ standard supported by the `/std:` argument of MSVC is c++14. (Hence, the red color of the check mark in Compiler Explorer...)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat yes you are correct, I forgot about it, just updated values without thinking :/.